# Laravel and AJAX 401 Unauthorised

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

How do i get my code so that if the 401 error appears with my AJAX button click code, then it either throws an error message when the button is clicked and says "you need to log in" or it redirects the user to login? at the moment it just throws the error in the dev console so a user has no idea on why the button isnt working.

Ajax js:

```
$('.visit').on('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// Make the button a variable here
var buttonToChange = $(this);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlVisit,
    data: {
        place_id: $(event.target).data("id"),
        _token: token
    },
    success: function(){
    // Change the button here
        if(buttonToChange.hasClass('btn-visited')){
            buttonToChange.addClass('btn-not-visited');
            buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-visited');
            buttonToChange.html('Not Visited');
        //Count will go down
        }
        else{
            // Do the opposite
            buttonToChange.addClass('btn-visited');
            buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-not-visited');
            buttonToChange.html('Visited');
//count will go up
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## simple example

you can test this code by `inspect` in browser:

`welcome.blade.php` :

```
    <script>
        var urlVisit="{{route('route_test')}}"
        var token = "{{csrf_token()}}"
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlVisit,
            data: {
                place_id: 1,
                _token: token
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert('ok')

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                if (xhr.status == 419)
                {
                    alert(xhr.responseText) // text of error

                    // do something
                }
                else if(xhr.status == 401)
                {
                    // do something
                }

            }

        });
    </script>
```

`web.php` (route) :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('test', function (Request $request) {
    $place_id= $request->get('place_id');
    return ('yes');
})->name('route_test');
```

Comment: how does that handle the 401 unauthorized message. I know what the message is, i just want to either display an error message or redirect instead of nothing which appears at the moment when i get this error.

Comment: handle in frontend?

Comment: yes i want to handle the 401 in the frontend by either displaying an error message prompting the user to log in or actually redirecting them to the login page

Comment: No luck with that code my friend, the error still shows without any changes ive placed in the if else

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `statusCode` part of jQuery AJAX.

```
$('.visit').on('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// Make the button a variable here
var buttonToChange = $(this);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlVisit,
    data: {
        place_id: $(event.target).data("id"),
        _token: token
    },
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            alert( "Not authenticated" );
        }
    }
success: function(){
// Change the button here
    if(buttonToChange.hasClass('btn-visited')){
        buttonToChange.addClass('btn-not-visited');
        buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-visited');
        buttonToChange.html('Not Visited');
    //Count will go down
    }
    else{
        // Do the opposite
        buttonToChange.addClass('btn-visited');
        buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-not-visited');
        buttonToChange.html('Visited');
//count will go up
    }
},
});
```